# Is it possible to combat SR Latch oscillation or there are better alternatives?

Tags: latch, data, oscillation, storage, data-storage

I need to store a bit value and then ignore any attempts to store/change it again until it's reset by another signal. So I figured the SR Latch is suited for the task. However in my project there is a possibility that SET and RESET will be turned on or off at the exact same time. Which of course causes oscillation. I know that in real life oscillations typically auto-resolve. But my project will run in a simulation where all "wires" and "gates" have the same delay.

Are there any extra modifications that can be done to prevent this from happenning? Or am I approaching it in a wrong way and should use a whole different structure for that?

Screenshot of simulation in Logisim Evolution:

[image: SR Latch Oscillation]

**UPDATE:**

A bit more details for those who requested:
When a button is pressed I want to set a bit to 1 and then ignore all subsequent button presses until that bit is reset to 0 by another signal automatically in X seconds.
The issue happens if button up (SET signal changes from 1 to 0) and reset signal on->off (again 1 to 0) happen at the same time.

**UPDATE2:**

So basically I need an SR Latch that allows both S=1,R=1 at the same time and prioritises S over R in that case. I tried to use S=S and S=(NOT) AND R to make sure that S excludes R but it seems that because the NOT gate takes time to switch the input it could result in both S=1 and R=1.

So here is my attempt at solving the issue. I've done some tests and it seems to work, at least for now. [Logisim Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AzpMPufiaLiILcXNsKMcALrjcP67gS2J/view?usp=share_link)

[image]

1. Both S and R are fed into Master-Slave D Flip-Flops. This syncronizes the changes and limits how often they can occur.
2. It seems because of the clock when a D Flip-Flop is switched on or off, Q and NOTQ **both turn 0** before one of them turning 1.
3. Which makes it seem possible to use Q and NOTQ in subsequent condition that prioritises S over R.

**UPDATE3:** Nvm, my circuit doesn't really eliminate the issue, at least completely. If S and R are set to 1 for just one tick (in step-by-step mode when clock is 1) and then back to 0, the whole system oscillates. Maybe the solution is to increase the clock time? From one full cycle taking 2 ticks to 8?

Comment: Why do you think it would cause oscillation?

Comment: When both S and R are 1, this is how the system looks: https://ibb.co/BrH2x18 . When they turn 0 at the same time, the output of both NOR gates becomes 1 (because each NOR input is 0), but since they feed into each other, NOR inputs are 1 and 0. So the output of NOR gates becomes 0. And again, and again.

Comment: It's really impossible to answer properly without knowing what's driving S, R and the CLR you mention. Please can you edit your question and add this info in detail with an explanation of what it's all for (don't add it in comments). An overall schematic too, as well as the text. Thanks.

Comment: Your statement of what could happen - does happen - is right. Do you know how your simulation program handles it? It's a common problem and there must be some way it's dealt with. In real life If both inputs can go low at the same time, the state the flipflop ends up in, in that case, must be unimportant.

Comment: TonyM, added more info. stretch, what do you mean by "Do you know how your simulation program handles it?"? It goes into an endless loop since all resistances and travel times are equal. If classic flip flop is not suited for this task, then I'd like to know what does.

Comment: Thanks for some detail but still don't understand what S, R and CLR are driven by and why. Lots more detail and a schematic showing the switch and other signal circuitry would resolve that. Otherwise, no-one knows why these signals need to behave in this way. Few here will want to spend time producing a complicated circuit doing what you've sketchily described so far, only to discover (or not) that some simple mods to what drives them would produce a far simpler circuit overall, for example. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you can attract.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly I should describe? The behaviour I listed is exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Sure, please can you edit your question and: **(1)** provide a circuit diagram showing of all the circuitry driving S. **(2)** same as (1) for R. **(3)** same as (1) for CLR. **(4)** describe in detail what the whole system does and why. **(5)** describe what the switch does when pressed and why.

Comment: @user64657 what I meant was that your simulation program must have a way to deal with metastability. It happens often and there must be at least a semi-realistic answer. Oscillating forever is not realistic, as you pointed out. Have you tried it and seen what happens? Your question is more about simulation programs than the circuits they simulate. There are lots of ways to get around metastability problems but no one will give you a good way until you say more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Maybe you can use the Andorian logic :-). First input goes to an OR whose output is fed back to an AND with NOT the other signal and its result is passed to the first OR. A temporary high to the OR will latch the output to high, and in order to reset it you need to supply a zero to the second input of the AND (a one if you NOT it). I am doing this in my head without pencil and paper, so check it out, I might have missed a not here or there.

Comment: Added my attempt on implementing it. It seems to work but I may be wrong.

Comment: I embrace the requests for more information. Typically you would not mix clocked latches/flip-flops with an SR flip-flop -- one reason being precisely that you want to avoid both S and R changing state simultaneously. So, I would either go with synchronous (i.e. clocked) circuitry, or asynchronous (unclocked) circuitry, but not try to mix them.

Comment: Going for async is not suitable for my task because it has a chance for a race condition/oscillation, right? So if I understand this correctly I should change SR Latch into SR Flip-Flop AND make sure that my Full Clock interval is higher than the time it takes for my whole circuit (input, transformation, output) to be processed.

Comment: It is often wise to work out the details of what you want before you jump into making implementation choices. An async circuit _can_ have race conditions and/or oscillations, but knowing the details of the _problem you are trying to solve_ will help to clarify what you do or do not need in a circuit. For example, what is the timer that resets the circuit? Could you have two timers, one that shortens the pulse generated by the push-button, and another to (later) reset the circuit? I would really like you to explain what you are doing in greater detail.

Comment: The SET signal can either be anything between a short pulse and staying on for a long time. When SET becomes 0 even for a moment, it triggers the "send RESET in X seconds" timer. I have little control(!) of that timer (can only change the delay). The timer sends a short pulse, although I can turn it into "stay 1 for a while". If timer delay is 10 seconds and SET turns 0 and then turns 1 and 0 at 2 seconds and then once again at 5 seconds, timer will 'remember' that and will send 3 pulses. On 10, 12 and 15 seconds respectively.

Answer (score 0):

> So I figured the SR Latch is suited for the task. However, in my project there is a possibility that SET and RESET will be turned on or off at the exact same time. Which of course causes oscillation. I know that in real life oscillations typically auto-resolve.

No, these oscillations don't auto-resolve ... unless you resolve it in the Karnaugh map.

You should do a "complete" analysis as this.
The interactive simulator is interesting but can lack some things.

The boxed circuit is used for filling the Karnaugh map : Q=f(R, S, q).
When filled, search the "stable" states (q)=(Q), and circle these states.
Then you can "follow" the behavior (changing R & S) of this circuit (rewire between q1 and Q1, second circuit) with gates having "delay".

[image]

But this is not the "true behavior".

In fact, one must consider that the circuit is symmetrical? (Q1,Q1)=f(q1,q2,R,S).

And this is the new circuit ... and how it "must" be considered.

[image]

One can see that the instability occurs "only" when (R1,S1) falls **simultaneously** to 0.
And this occurs not too often, unless "done" on purpose.
See the different behavior when gates have "no delay" or some "delay".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it were up to me, I would not use a latch for this, but a D flip-flop with asynchronous clear, and the D input wired to constant `1`.

The external event changes the output immediately, and a clock pulse rearms the state.

The asynchronous clear takes precedence over the clock -- a clock edge will be ignored it it arrives during asynchronous clear, which can alternatively be treated as the external input no longer being ignored as a reset of rearming, and immediately affecting the output again.

You may need some inverters (NOT gates) if you are expecting inputs and outputs to be active-high.  But momentary buttons are almost always wired to output active-low.